# WPF Simple Binding to an objects property

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Im having some problems with binding in wpf/xaml. Have this simple file:

```
<Window x:Class="test.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Height="21" Foreground="Black" Margin="74,98,84,0" Name="textBlock1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding MyText}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Where i want to bind the content of the textblock to my property "MyText". My code looks like this:

```
 public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string MyText
        {
            get { return "This is a test"; }
        }
    }
```

All in all very simple, but when i start the textblock has no content - howcome?

Comment: UPDATE: I dont even get a breakpoint at the property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need an element name in your binding:

```
<Window ... x:Name="ThisWindow"...>

        <TextBlock ... Text="{Binding MyText, ElementName=ThisWindow}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm remembering my WPF binding syntax correctly, I believe your binding expression should read Text="{Binding Path=MyText}"

Comment: Tried that, no luck, still blank...
...Text="{Binding Path=MyText}" />

Comment: Tried source, just rendered the text "MyText" which is the name of the property...

Edit: the solution with a name in binding worked

Comment: Thanks for the refresher, it's been a while since I studied WPF :)

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this. Probably the easiest for something as simple as this form is:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```